# urllib3 shows debug and script stops without error message

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, python-requests, urllib

[image]

That is a screenshot from my VM running Ubuntu and python 2.7.15rc. I'm running a script with one function as such:

```
def get_price(symbol):

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?formatted=true&crumb=rc4xVliXUfL&lang=en-US&region=US&symbols={symbol}&fields=messageBoardId%2ClongName%2CshortName%2CmarketCap%2CunderlyingSymbol%2CunderlyingExchangeSymbol%2CheadSymbolAsString%2CregularMarketPrice%2CregularMarketChange%2CregularMarketChangePercent%2CregularMarketVolume%2Cuuid%2CregularMarketOpen%2CfiftyTwoWeekLow%2CfiftyTwoWeekHigh&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com'.format(symbol=symbol))
    return float(json.loads(r.data)['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['regularMarketPrice']['raw'])
```

I'm only assuming that the issue is with this because the last message it gives before the script fails is about this function running.

If I suppress warnings of unverified HTTPS request, it still does the same thing, just without those two warnings.

Also, this same script runs fine on my computer running macos and python 2.7.14

I really need all the help I can get, so I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Why are you running a release-candidate version of python for real tasks?

Comment: @snakecharmerb that's just what came installed on the linux VM. Does that seem like it could be the issue?

Comment: It's certainly possible. 2.7.15 final has been released so I'd suggest building a vm with that installed and trying again.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Just installed 3.6.5 and still getting the same issue

Comment: On 3.7, I see the InsecureRequestWarning if I run the code from the `get_price` function, but the function returns data (for symbol = 'INTC').
Perhaps you can print the value of `r.data` to see what you are getting back.

Comment: I figured it out, I had assumed that the hour returned from my datetime.now().hour would be in my timezone, but it was in UTC so the main while loop never ran so the script ended. Thanks for the help!